# Translate nginx location option to apache option

Tags: httpd.conf, nginx-config

How would you translate those nginx options (from [Laravel deployment documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#nginx)) to httpd.conf ?

```
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
```

Is there anything about location ?

Does it mean "Don't write to log if favicon.ico and robots.txt are not found" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it :

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/robots\.txt$" dontlog
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/favicon\.ico$" dontlog
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/my-access_log common env=!dontlog
```